# Radio streaming android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, internet-radio

Hi I want to implement a radio in my application...I wrote this code, it worked in the emulator YouWave but il dosen't worked in a SmartPhone and another tablet and I don't know why..can you help me please?

This is the code of the radio :

```
public class radio extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer media;
    Button buttonplay;
    Button buttonStopRecord;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.radio);


                buttonStopRecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Stop);
                buttonStopRecord.getBackground().setAlpha(150);
                buttonStopRecord.setEnabled(false);

                buttonStopRecord.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                  {

                    @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                         if ( media.isPlaying() ) {
                        media.stop();
                    }
                     }
                  });

                buttonplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
                buttonplay.getBackground().setAlpha(150);

                buttonplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                  {

                    @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                        try
                       {
                             media = new MediaPlayer();
                            media.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.USE_DEFAULT_STREAM_TYPE);
                            media.setDataSource("http://indiespectrum.com:9000");
                            media.prepare();
                            media.start();
                          if ( media.isPlaying()) {
                                buttonplay.setEnabled(false);

                                buttonStopRecord.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                        }
                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            //Getting Exception
                        }
                    }
                  });

                Button accueil=(Button)findViewById(R.id.accueilr);
              accueil.getBackground().setAlpha(200);
              accueil.getBackground().setAlpha(150);
                accueil.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                    try{    
                        if ( media.isPlaying() ) {
                            media.stop();
                        }
                    }catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Intent i=new Intent(radio.this,main.class);
                        startActivity(i);   
                    }
                        Intent i=new Intent(radio.this,main.class);
                        startActivity(i);           

                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you talking about Rdio, or is that a typo?

Comment: I don't Undersand what's typo?

Comment: there's a music streaming service called Rdio. Are you talking about that, or did you mean to type "Radio" in the question? I don't know much Java, I was just wondering.

Comment: I speak about radio streaming

Comment: "Doesn't work" in what way? And what about the logcat output? The more info you provide, the more likely you'll be to get an answer.

Comment: It shows me those errors in logcat   01-22 20:55:16.029: W/MediaPlayer(306): info/warning (1, 26)
01-22 20:55:16.050: E/MediaPlayer(306): error (1, -1)
01-22 20:55:16.060: I/MediaPlayer(306): Info (1,26)

Comment: Nothing happens when I push the button "Play"...but it works into emulator "YouWave"...and not in the smartphone

Comment: It seems that this code source dosen't work in an android version under than 2.3

Answer (score 0):

From what I know this code should work on every device with Api higher than 8.

```
   media = new MediaPlayer(); 
media.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
media.setDataSource("http://indiespectrum.com:9000"); 
media.prepareAsync(); 
media.seOnPreparedListener(this);
```

And inside the OnPrepared method put `media.start()`. This worked for me.